# How can I have multiple buttons with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I would like to create several boxes on my website with a "find out more" button. I found this code on the internet, this is exactly what I want.

But the problem is that I have to have several boxes and when I press one, all of them interact.

I don't know much about renaming my tags and I don't know if there is a simpler code for what I want.

At the beginning this code represented a registration form, I simply removed all the inputs.

I don't know much about javascript, can someone help me?

Thx

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Télécharger la méthodologie de la définition des enjeux et des objectifs";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "En savoir plus";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #76A6A7;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #76A6A7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

  <form id="regForm" action="https://www.google.fr">
    <h4>Définition des enjeux et des objectifs</h4>
    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
    <div class="tab">Carpe Minute aide l’organisateur à sécuriser 90% du projet dans les 15 premiers jours en définissant les enjeux, les objectifs et les indicateurs de réussite.
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Vous posez vous au moins l’une des questions suivantes :
      <ul>
        <li>Sommes-nous capables d'organiser ?</li>
        <li>Avons-nous les moyens financiers et humains ?</li>
        <li>Pourquoi le faisons-nous ? Dans quel(s) buts ?</li>
        <li>Les membres de l'équipe partagent-ils les mêmes objectifs ?</li>
        <li>Quels sont les conditions préalables de réussite?</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Exemple de réalisation :
      <p>Rhodia Club</p>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
      <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Retour</button>
        <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">En savoir plus</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px;">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
  </form>

<form id="regForm" action="https://www.google.fr">
<h4>Définition des enjeux et des objectifs</h4>
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">Carpe Minute aide l’organisateur à sécuriser 90% du projet dans les 15 premiers jours en définissant les enjeux, les objectifs et les indicateurs de réussite.
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="tab">Vous posez vous au moins l’une des questions suivantes :
  <ul>
    <li>Sommes-nous capables d'organiser ?</li>
    <li>Avons-nous les moyens financiers et humains ?</li>
    <li>Pourquoi le faisons-nous ? Dans quel(s) buts ?</li>
    <li>Les membres de l'équipe partagent-ils les mêmes objectifs ?</li>
    <li>Quels sont les conditions préalables de réussite?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab">Exemple de réalisation :
  <p>Rhodia Club</p>
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Retour</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">En savoir plus</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px;">
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
</div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code is for tabs, not "show more".

Comment: yes, i want tabs like my example.

Comment: Can you put multiple items in your example HTML so we can see the problem?

Comment: Done, as you can see when you press the "show more" bouton, the second block is activated

Comment: I'm so sorry btw my explanation was really bad ... I am a beginner and I am aware that it is a basic

Comment: This code you admit having found on internet can be optimized to handle many "boxes". But there a lot to be done. I think your question is too wide for SO. Any "short" answer is likely to be incomplete. And any "long" answer is likely to be too specific to the code you submited... Making it a "code request" answer.